# How to create sub-levels role in Spring Security 4?

Tags: spring-security, menu

one question for you. 
In my application I'm using Spring Security 4 .
Now, i would like to have a different level - role.
Look an example.

Now:

- role 1: admin;
- role 2: customer.

To be:

- role 1: admin;
- role 2 : customer A / customer B / customer C;

Then, i would like use spring security tag in my menu jsp page to obtain some different menu from customer A / customer B / customer C, in the same role (role2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a role hierarchy by exposing a `RoleHierarchy` bean.

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_ONE\nROLE_A > ROLE_TWO\nROLE_B > ROLE_TWO\nROLE_C > ROLE_TWO");
    return roleHierarchy;
}
```

This is saying that if a user is `"ROLE_ADMIN"` then they are also `"ROLE_ONE"`.
If a user is `"ROLE_A"` then they are also `"ROLE_TWO"`.
If a user is `"ROLE_B"` then they are also `"ROLE_TWO"`.
If a user is `"ROLE_C"` then they are also `"ROLE_TWO"`.
You can define multiple role hierarchies by using a newline `\n` to separate them.